# Need to create a list of student names

Tags: python

hey i need to create a list of student names, but i am stuck because i am meant to keep prompting the user to add names until they enter a blank space "" but the program stops after 3 entries, i am new to python can anyone help?

```
studentnames = []
studentnames.append(input("Enter a name:"))
inp = studentnames.append(input("Enter a name"))      
while inp != "": 
  inp = studentnames.append(input("Enter a name"))
  break

print(studentnames)
for index,letter in enumerate(studentnames,1):
  print(index,":",letter)
```

Comment: don't `break`..

Answer (score 0):

```
while inp != "": 
  inp = studentnames.append(input("Enter a name"))
  break
```

You should not `break` here, otherwise the loop just stop after executed once.

Answer (score 0):

LIST.append('toto') return `None`.

So after this line `inp = studentnames.append(input("Enter a name"))`.
 `inp = None`

Change it to:

```
studentnames.append(input("Enter a name"))
inp = studentnames[-1]  # last index
```

And don't `break` inside the while